# How to make java string colored when sending mail using SimpleMailMessage class

Tags: java, spring, email

I am sending mail using SimpleMailMessage class in java.I am using spring with hibernate.I want to set a particular string to colored when sending mail.

Code:

```
    String emailBody = "Dear "+username;
    SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();  
    simpleMailMessage.setFrom("My Name <myemail>");
    simpleMailMessage.setTo(mailid);
    simpleMailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    simpleMailMessage.setText(emailBody);       
    mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
```

I want to set username as blue colored when sending mail.I searched a lot, But only saw  mimemessage's method ie,mimemessage.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
The simplemailmessage doesn't have the setcontent() method.Is there any way to set color ?

Comment: To use colours and fonts you'll need to send the email as an HTML email and then use HTML tags and style tags to make the email appear as you wish. Think of the email as a mini-website when it comes to styling and such. I am not sure this can be done with SimpleMailMessage. I suggest using Message and using Transport to send the message.

Comment: I also applied the html tags into my code.ie, String emailBody = "<h1>Dear  </h1>"+username;    It results <h1>Dear </h1> within the mail body

Comment: The class SimpleMailMessage, is this from the Spring library? If so they have guidelines in their documentation that to sent more complex emails to use a different class. It appears SimpleMailMessage is plaintext and cannot be used to sent HTML emails. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289849/how-do-i-send-html-email-in-spring-mvc) and use style and html elements to add colors.

Answer (score 3):

The [Spring 4.2.1 documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html) states, that you should use *MimeMessage* instead of *SimpleMailMessage* if you want colors. Here is how I do it in my code:

```
        MimeMessagePreparator mailMessage = mimeMessage -> {

            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(
                    mimeMessage, true, ENCODING);
            try {
                message.setFrom(senderEmail, senderName);
                for (String addr : recipientEmails) {
                    message.addTo(addr);
                }
                message.setReplyTo(senderEmail);
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setText(fallbackTextContent, htmlContent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new MailDeliveryServiceException(recpStr, e);
            }
        };
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
```

As Daniel mentioned above *htmlContent* is basically a small webpage without relative links. *fallbackTextContent* is the plain text for mail clients that do not support HTML.